# How to import php my admin .sql file into SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to import the .sql file of PHP myadmin into SQL Server 2008.

I created a new database, then click on new query and paste .sql script of php and execute the command. it's giving syntax errors.

Can we directly import that .sql of php into SQL Server 2008?

Comment: MySQL and MSSQL are not interchangable.

Comment: You can import it only if you use only pure standard SQL functionality. Which, these days, is pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at this blog post - [MySQL to SQL Server Migration: How to Use SSMA](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/02/07/mysql-to-sql-server-migration-how-to-use-ssma.aspx?Redirected=true)

Using SQL Server Migration Assistant you can migrate from a mysql database to server 2008, from an active connection, not a sql dump. You could create another MySQL database temporarily if you cannot connect remotely to the original database. This utility will let you know any issues that might arise with the migration.